# Jwt Authentication with Angular

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt

I am new to angular, what I am trying to implement is I want authService to apply the login subscription so that I can keep the token inside authService to be accessable for all components, but also send the result to LoginComponent to act upon it (either redirect to home page or show error)

authService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  
  authToken : string | undefined;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(email: string, password: string){
    this.http
    .post<string>(
                  'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/login',
                  {email: email, password: password}
                  )
    .subscribe(token => this.authToken = token);
  }
}
```

LoginComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{
  authenticated = false;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  login(loginForm: NgForm) {
    let email = loginForm.form.value.email;
    let password = loginForm.form.value.password;
    this.authService.login(email, password);
  }
}
```

I've tried to apply subscription in LoginComponent but then I couldn't set authToken in authService, now I applied subscription in authService 'which I think is the better option' but I don't know how to still send the success or error to the component to act upon it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to solve it using tap() operator of [rxjs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap)

here is the implementation of AuthService

```
export class AuthService {
  
  authToken : string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(email: string, password: string){
    this.http
    .post<string>('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/login', {email: email, password: password})
    .pipe(
      tap(token => {
        this.authToken = token;
        this.setToken(token)
      })
    );
  }
```